# Trying to get 1 day or 2min ago from a timestamp in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want to auto convert timestamps to things like that :

X min ago
X hour ago
X month ago

But i dont know what to do after :

```
function getTimeAgo(timestamp){
 var a = new Date(timestamp*1000);
 ..
}
```

I'm new with javascript, does anyone has already coded that kind of function ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a specific blogging platform? If you are uncomfortable or unfamiliar with Javascript you could use jQuery, which is plugins for Javascript, or PHP.

Comment: http://timeago.yarp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TimeAgo.js](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

> ## What?
>
> Timeago is a jQuery plugin that makes it easy to support
>   automatically updating fuzzy timestamps (e.g. "4 minutes ago" or
>   "about 1 day ago"). Download, view the examples, and enjoy.
>
> You opened this page less than a minute ago. (This will update every
>   minute. Wait for it.)
>
> This page was last modified about a month ago.
>
> Ryan was born 34 years ago.
>
> ## Usage:
>
> ```
> jQuery.timeago(new Date());             //=> "less than a minute ago"
> jQuery.timeago("2008-07-17");           //=> "5 years ago"
> jQuery.timeago(jQuery("abbr#some_id")); //=> "5 years ago"     // [title="2008-07-20"]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), the time format you want is found under [humanize](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/)

example taken from the docs *(not tested)*:

```
var a = new Date(timestamp*1000).getMilliseconds();
moment.duration(a, "minutes").humanize(true); // will output "n minute ago"
```

**Update**

as requested in the comments, here some examples in a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/tXDA3/1/)

Hope it helps

Comment: I just downloaded the library but i'm not familiar with JS, can u make me an example to get from a timestamp thinks like this :  X second ago, X minutes ago etc?

Comment: Thanks but will it show X hours ago if minutes are > 60 ? And same with the days and month..